# how do i configure systems from github

Tags: configuration

when I configure mydlp from Github I get the following error
 please help me

beam/beam_load.c(1158): Error loading module compile:
  mandatory chunk of type 'Atom' not found

root@mydlp01:/home/mydlp# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for erlc... /usr/bin/erlc
checking for a prefix by checking for erl... /usr/bin/erl
checking for erl... /usr/bin/erl
checking for Erlang/OTP root directory... configure: error: in `/home/mydlp':
configure error: test Erlang program execution failed
See`config.log' for more details

Answer (score 0):

The system is telling you that some data in the *byte code* is missing. If you want to start reading up, you can start [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html). In my experience this is probably due to you having compiled it using Erlang with version *X* and now you are running it and loading it using Erlang with version *Y*.